# No es una función?

Tags: javascript

Por qúe al ejecutarlo (dando click en cualquiera de los 3 botones de arriba y luego en el boton crear pasajero), me da error?, por qué no es una función?

```js
// ** Usando constructor **

function Pasajero(identificador, nombre, email, celular, edad) {
  
  this.identificador = identificador;
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.email = email;
  this.celular = celular;
  this.edad = edad;
  
  }

// Variables globales

var efectivo = document.getElementById('efectivo');
var cheque = document.getElementById('cheque');
var tarjeta = document.getElementById('tarjeta');
var evento = document.getElementById('crear');
var pasajeros = []; // Cantidad de pasajeros .length
var persona = "";
var pago = "";

// ** Fin Constructor **
  
// ** Prototipo del constructor **

Pasajero.prototype = {
  
  formaDePago: function() {
    
    if (efectivo) {
      pago = 'efectivo';
    }
    else if(cheque) {
      pago = 'cheque';
    }
    else if(tarjeta){
      pago = 'tarjeta';
    }
    else {
      console.log("Selecciona método de pago por favor");
    }
    console.log(pago);
    
  }
  
};


// Añadimos un evento con una función anónima..
evento.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  persona = new Pasajero((pasajeros.length + 1), "aena", "aena@gmail.com", "+56958274822", "24" );
  pasajeros.push((pasajeros.length + 1));
// Recorremos el array
pasajeros.forEach(function(e){console.log(e);});

// Recorremos el objeto creado del constructor
for (var i in persona) {
  
  document.write(i + ": " + (typeof persona[i] === 'function') ? persona[i]() : persona[i]);
 
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="array">
    <input type="button" id="efectivo" value="Efectivo"/>
  <input type="button" id="cheque" value="Cheque"/>
  <input type="button" id="tarjeta" value="Tarjeta"/>
  <hr></hr>
  <input type="button" id="crear" value="Crear Pasajero"/>
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Las maravillas de los lenguajes sin tipado fuerte...

```
document.write(i + ": " + (typeof persona[i] === 'function') ? persona[i]() : persona[i]);
```

Lo que está a la izquierda del `?` es `i + ": " + (typeof persona[i] === 'function')`, que es una expresión de tipo string.

El operador `?` lo interpreta como `true`, y ejecuta `persona[i]()`. Tu lo que quieres es

```
document.write(i + ": " + (typeof persona[i] === 'function' ? persona[i]() : persona[i]));
```

Un error muy espectaculara para un fallo muy sencillo. De hecho, estoy convencido de que si hubieras intentado hacer un ejemplo mínimo lo habrías encontrado tú mismo.

Aquí abajo el *snippet* corregido:

```js
// ** Usando constructor **

function Pasajero(identificador, nombre, email, celular, edad) {
  
  this.identificador = identificador;
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.email = email;
  this.celular = celular;
  this.edad = edad;
  
  }

// Variables globales

var efectivo = document.getElementById('efectivo');
var cheque = document.getElementById('cheque');
var tarjeta = document.getElementById('tarjeta');
var evento = document.getElementById('crear');
var pasajeros = []; // Cantidad de pasajeros .length
var persona = "";
var pago = "";

// ** Fin Constructor **
  
// ** Prototipo del constructor **

Pasajero.prototype = {
  
  formaDePago: function() {
    
    if (efectivo) {
      pago = 'efectivo';
    }
    else if(cheque) {
      pago = 'cheque';
    }
    else if(tarjeta){
      pago = 'tarjeta';
    }
    else {
      console.log("Selecciona método de pago por favor");
    }
    console.log(pago);
    
  }
  
};


// Añadimos un evento con una función anónima..
evento.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  persona = new Pasajero((pasajeros.length + 1), "aena", "aena@gmail.com", "+56958274822", "24" );
  pasajeros.push((pasajeros.length + 1));
// Recorremos el array
pasajeros.forEach(function(e){console.log(e);});

// Recorremos el objeto creado del constructor
for (var i in persona) {
  
  document.write(i + ": " + (typeof persona[i] === 'function' ? persona[i]() : persona[i]));
 
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="array">
    <input type="button" id="efectivo" value="Efectivo"/>
  <input type="button" id="cheque" value="Cheque"/>
  <input type="button" id="tarjeta" value="Tarjeta"/>
  <hr></hr>
  <input type="button" id="crear" value="Crear Pasajero"/>
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias! juan